# Fast hidden surface determination on vertices

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, shader

I have a very expensive vertex shader, and therefore I want to minimize the amount of polygons rendered.

I can do a reasonable amount of culling on the cpu, but it's not going down to the per polygon or per vertex level, which I want. My goal is performance.

Is there a fast technique to do this?

Edit: I know the vertex shader can change the position of the vertices, however that's not why the vertex shader is expensive. So I am allowed to compute the position position of the vertex, in some pipeline, then later compute the rest per vertex, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do any per primitive operations in the vertex shader because you only get one vertex at a time. If you're using DirectX 11, however, you can in general move a lot of expensive per vertex calculations over to the tesselation stage. That is even if you don't do any tesselation. The advantage of doing this is that you can cull back-facing triangles in the tesselation stage before doing expensive calculations on their vertices. For more info on how to do this, do a search on tesselation back-face culling. As a bonus, you can even do per triangle frustum culling.

This method is faster and easier that using a compute shader or doing it on the CPU.

Comment: In fact, it is possible to cull a triangle in the vertex shader by outputting NANs in the clip space position of any involve vertex. Not a good solution here as the vertex still only cares of one third of the triangle, but it is sometime handy.

Comment: Also, the tessellation stage cost is worst with low tessellation value. All my test (AMD and nVidia) showed that with a tessellation value bellow 8, drawing the same geometry with a pre-generated tessellation is quite faster, by a large amount, even with a crazy amount of bandwidth addition to stream the data.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your exact situation. If you can relatively easily render (more or less) front to back, and it's often the case that entire objects are hidden, OpenGL occlusion queries could be a very useful tool.

The idea behind occlusion queries is that you render your geometry with a very simple shader, and get a result that tells you if it resulted in any visible rendering. Then, if it generated visible pixels, you actually render it with the full shaders. If the query result tells you that it's completely hidden, you skip the rendering. It's also common to use simplified geometry, e.g. a bounding box, when submitting the draw commands for the occlusion query.

Occlusion queries can be somewhat tricky to use efficiently because you have to wait until the GPU finished the query before you can read back the result. This can produce undesirable synchronization between CPU and GPU if you're not very careful. There is a newer approach called "conditional rendering" that avoids this. The idea here is that you always submit the full draw commands, but tell the GPU to skip them depending on the result of the query. The downside compared to occlusion queries is that you always have the CPU overhead for submitting the draw commands. But depending on the use case, this can still be much better than dealing with the synchronization and possible stalls that can happen with traditional occlusion queries.

If you can't easily render front to back, you could also consider a two pass approach. You could render all geometry with very simple shaders, while writing to the depth buffer only (disable color writes). Then submit occlusion queries for all your objects, and based on the query results render the visible objects with your full shaders.

Answer (score -1):

In your context, i would proceed add a compute shader.

The shader will read the triangle list as a buffer of index, retrieve the position and other values needed to perform the transformation from the vertex buffer mapped as a StructuredBuffer. Then, if culling claims a visible triangle, output the three indices into the final index buffer, and add three to the index count in a small buffer. At the end, you will be able to use `DrawIndexedInstancedIndirect` to render the culled geometry with the correct amount of index.

Comment: How do i determine if something is culled or not?

Comment: One solution is to compute the normal with a cross product with two edges of the triangle, then check if it is facing or not the view direction. If you transform the position in the view space, then it is as easily as looking at the sign of the z component of the normal ( when z axis is is the depth ).